# Recursive exceptions to exclusions in .dockerignore not working as expected

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerignore

I'm dockerizing a PHP-based application. I've got an nginx container containing `.js`, `.html` and `.css` files along with all assets. For the PHP code, I'm using a dedicated [PHP Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=description) which is proxied by the nginx server. I would like to only have `.php` files in that PHP image, without any of the assets or *public* files.

In order to keep the resulting image as small as possible, but still easily maintain the files copied in my image, I want to make use of the [.dockerignore whitelist pattern](https://kevinpollet.dev/posts/how-to-use-your-dockerignore-as-a-whitelist/). Somehow, I can't ignore all files and make exceptions for files in any directory for a specific file type.

In my special case, I want to ignore any file by default. Then, I would like to 'allow' php files. Those are nested in sub directories. It looks like that the `.dockerigone` doesn't catch these files in ignored directories **if** they aren't found somehow else.

My `.dockerignore` is located in `app/`.

### Case 1

Consider the following directory structure:

```
app
├── index.php
├── controllers
│   ├── controller-1.php
│   ├── controller-2.php
│   └── controller-3.php
└── models
    ├── index.php
    ├── checkout
    │   ├── model-1.php
    │   ├── model-2.php
    │   └── model-3.php
    ├── profile
    │   ├── model-1.php
    │   ├── model-2.php
    │   └── model-3.php
    └── registration
        ├── model-1.php
        ├── model-2.php
        └── model-3.php
```

And the following `.dockerignore` file:

```
# Ignore all files by default.
**

!**/*.php
```

The container will contain the following files:

```
app
└── index.php
```

### Case 2

Using a more descriptive `.dockerignore` will show subdirectories:

```
# Ignore all files by default.
**

!controllers/*.php
!models/*.php
```

But still don't lead to the desired result:

```
app
├── index.php
├── controllers
│   ├── controller-1.php
│   ├── controller-2.php
│   └── controller-3.php
└── models
    └── index.php
```

### Case 3

But if directories are known to the Docker daemon, it works in these but only these directories:

```
# Ignore all files by default.
**

!**/*.php
!models/checkout/model-1.php
```

will result in:

```
app
├── index.php
└── models
    ├── index.php
    └── checkout
        ├── model-1.php
        ├── model-2.php
        └── model-3.php
```

### Question

Does anyone has an idea how to resolve the issue? I know what I'm doing might be a bit more special, but somehow I expect to work like that. The workaround to specifically list all directories I would like to have included. Still, the reverse way works well (excluding a specific file type in any directory like `**/.DS_STORE`). If there isn't a logic error and there is no clear solution, I would file in a bug on GitHub. Thanks in advance. Otherwise, I would like to extend the docs of Docker.